# How to detect when a specific window is closed in java

Tags: java, events, window, action, windowlistener

I'm pretty new to Java and I've tried looking this up but couldn't really find any thing that helped. I'm wondering how I could detect when a specific window is closed? I've been using windowClosing() but this applies to any window that is closed, and so the event that I would want to happen as a result of window A closing also happens if window B closes. How do I go about detecting only if window A is closed? Sorry if this is worded badly, I don't know that much Java terminology. Thanks in advance :)

```
package gui_login;

//awt classes
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

//swing classes
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class windowtest implements ActionListener, WindowListener
{
//get JFrame
    JFrame JFrame = new JFrame();

    public static JFrame frameA = new JFrame("FrameA");
    public static JFrame frameB = new JFrame("FrameB");
    static windowtest windowtest = new windowtest();

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    windowtest.frames();
}

public void frames()
{
    frameA.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frameA.setSize(220, 130);
    frameA.setVisible(true);
    frameA.addWindowListener(this);

    frameB.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frameB.setSize(220, 130);
    frameB.setVisible(true);
    frameB.addWindowListener(this);
}

public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Yo");
}
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
}
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
}
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {
}
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {
}
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
}
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
}
}
```

Comment: Add a `WindowListener` to `A`

Comment: [How to Write Window Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, that is basically what I have been using, but the windowclosing() event happens no matter which window I close, because I have a windowlistener on both a and b

Comment: So, use a unquie instance for both (so each window get's it's own listener), otherwise Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Okay so I got an example ready, how do I post it?

Comment: Edit your question and post it there

Comment: Okay I have done that thanks :), so as you can see, I have no idea how to create a 'unique instance' for both like you said was needed, and no matter which window is closed, "Yo" is printed out on the console. How do I go about changing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because both `frameA` and `frameB` are using the same instance of `WindowListener` (this), when either frame is closed, your `WindowListener` is notified (of both/either).

You could use `WindowEvent#getSource` to get the source of the event, but a easier solution might be to give each frame their own instance of a `WindowListener`, this way, you don't need to make assumptions about what's going

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class WindowTest {
//get JFrame

    JFrame JFrame = new JFrame();

    public static JFrame frameA = new JFrame("FrameA");
    public static JFrame frameB = new JFrame("FrameB");
    static WindowTest windowtest = new WindowTest();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                windowtest.frames();
            }
        });
    }

    public void frames() {
        frameA.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frameA.setSize(220, 130);
        frameA.setVisible(true);
        frameA.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.out.println("A is closing");
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                System.out.println("A has closed");
            }

        });

        frameB.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frameB.setSize(220, 130);
        frameB.setVisible(true);
        frameB.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.out.println("B is closing");
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                System.out.println("B has closed");
            }

        });
    }
}
```

You may not have seen anonymous classes before, take a look at [Anonymous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Generally speaking, it's no longer required that you implement interfaces which don't provide direct functionality to your class (like you have with `ActionListener` and `WindowListener`), the reasoning is, the methods which these interfaces require you to implement are `public`, but no one should really be calling them directly.

This allows you to "hide" the implementation details internally to your class and prevents possible mis-use by unknown callers

You may also want to take a look at [Nested Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)